# PHP Regular Expression to extract JSON data

Tags: php, regex

I have the following string:

```
window['test'] = false; 
window['options'] = true; 
window['data'] = { "id" : 2345, "stuff": [{"id":704,"name":"test"};`
```

How would I go about extracting the JSON data in `window['data']`? The example data I provided is just a small sample of what really exists. There *could* be more data before and/or after `window['data']`.

I've tried this but had no luck:

```
preg_match( '#window["test"] = (.*?);\s*$#m', $html, $matches );
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Matching `;` as the end of the JSON value is not safe. What happens if the JSON data contains the `;` character?

Comment: I think you already asked this question..

Comment: Are you sure you're getting a string with that info in it? It fails to pass as a string, it would have to be escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues that I can see.

1. Your string uses single quotes: `window['test']` not `window["test"]`, which you have in your regular expression.  This means you should use double quotes to enclose your regular expression (or escape the quotes).
2. Your regular expression has unescaped brackets, which is used to create a character class.  You should use `\[` instead of just `[`.
3. You say you are looking for `data` but your regular expression looks for `test`.
4. You have a `$` at the end of the regular expression, which means you won't match if there is nothing other than whitespace after the bit you matched.

Also your data seems incomplete, there are some missing brackets at the end, but I think that is just a copy-paste error.

So I would try:

`php > preg_match("#window\['data'\]\s*=\s*(.*?);#", $html, $matches);
php > print_r($matches);
Array
(
    [0] => window['data'] = {"id":2345,"stuff":[{"id":704,"name":"test"};
    [1] => {"id":2345,"stuff":[{"id":704,"name":"test"}
)`

Of course then you must use `json_decode()` to convert the JSON string (`$matches[1]`) into an object or associative array that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
window\['data'\]\s*=\s*(.*?);
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/eP8uG0/2)**

[image]

The match information is:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [67-111]    `{"id":2345,"stuff":[{"id":704,"name":"test"}`
```

As regex101 suggests you could have a code like this:

```
$re = "/window\\['data'\\]\\s*=\\s*(.*);/"; 
$str = "window['test'] = false; window['options'] = true; window['data'] = {\"id\":2345,\"stuff\":[{\"id\":704,\"name\":\"test\"};"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the `window` data with the regular expression:

```
/^window\[['"](\w+)['"]\]\s*=\s*(.+);\s*$/m
```

*Then* you can retrieve the pieces by their original index in the `window` data structures, and parse the JSON at your leisure.

```php
$data = <<<_E_
window['test'] = false;
window['options'] = true;
window['data'] = { "id" : 2345, "stuff": [{"id":704,"name":"test"}]};
_E_;
$regex = <<<_E_
/^window\[['"](\w+)['"]\]\s*=\s*(.+);\s*$/m
_E_; // SO syntax highlighting doesnt like HEREDOCs "

if( preg_match_all($regex,$data,$matches) > 0 ) {
    var_dump($matches);
    $index = array_search('data',$matches[1]);
    if( $index !== 0 ) {
        var_dump(json_decode($matches[2][$index]));
    } else { echo 'no data section'; }
} else { echo 'no matches'; }
```

Output:

```
// $matches
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>    string(24) "window['test'] = false; "
    [1]=>    string(26) "window['options'] = true; "
    [2]=>    string(69) "window['data'] = { "id" : 2345, "stuff": [{"id":704,"name":"test"}]};"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>    string(4) "test"
    [1]=>    string(7) "options"
    [2]=>    string(4) "data"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>    string(5) "false"
    [1]=>    string(4) "true"
    [2]=>    string(51) "{ "id" : 2345, "stuff": [{"id":704,"name":"test"}]}"
  }
}
// decoded JSON
object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
  ["id"]=>      int(2345)
  ["stuff"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#2 (2) {
      ["id"]=>      int(704)
      ["name"]=>    string(4) "test"
    }
  }
}
```

Note: I fixed the JSON in your example to be valid so it would actually parse.